# What part of the sentence is modified by "as descents to mental ineptitude"?

Tags: modifiers

> But it is more important not to think lies, or to slide into those
>   mechanical and untruthful habits of thought which are so pleasant and
>   so easy **as descents to mental ineptitude**.

Which one below is modified by "**as descents to mental ineptitude**"?

(1) to slide

(2) habits

(3) so pleasant and so easy

I would choose (2).

Comment: the verb is descend, the noun is descent. Please check your sources.

Comment: @Lambie, thanks, it's "descents." For some reason, Google Books does not display the contents on that particular page. https://books.google.com/books?id=_-PzdXhnhLIC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22pleasant+and+so+easy+as+descents+to+mental+ineptitude%22&source=bl&ots=xDQALg5GyI&sig=ACfU3U3yoQVI7EE5mT5sAfYL5qMiKKjMJw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7v6-rlbLiAhUKQq0KHU43DQoQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22pleasant%20and%20so%20easy%20as%20descents%20to%20mental%20ineptitude%22&f=false

Comment: Ah right, OK. Well, yes, habits of thought. :)

Comment: @Lambie I think *descents* makes sense as a noun in this context. Normally in modern (American) English we would say "descents *into* X" but this is my understanding. I agree that the answer is 2.

Comment: @Mixolydian Didn't you see my next comment? descents into x is not American English. It's just English.

Comment: Plural noun ***descents*** here is equivalent to ***downward paths*** (or ***trips, excursions***) *[into mental ineptitude / moral turpitude / bad habits / etc]*. But it's a fairly complex (verbose? pompous?) writing style, probably not a useful study aid for most learners.

Comment: @Lambie now I do. Glad we are on the same page. My point was "descents *to*" looks strange to me, and I would prefer "descents *into*", but perhaps it would seem normal to a speaker of another dialect. Maybe it's more a matter of old-fashioned vs. contemporary English.

Comment: I agree that the pronoun is awkward. It would be much more common to write *as descents **into** mental ineptitude*.

Answer (score -1):

> But it is more important not to think lies, or to slide into those mechanical and untruthful habits of thought which are so pleasant and so easy **as descents to mental ineptitude**.

Semantically speaking, the phrase in bold refers to "those mechanical and untruthful habits of thought." From a syntactic point of view, the phrase could be analyzed as an extraposed apposition which requires "as" to be able to be placed in that end position:

- Those mechanical and untruthful habits of thought, **descents to mental ineptitude**, are so pleasant and so easy.
- Those mechanical and untruthful habits of thought  are so pleasant and so easy, **AS descents to mental ineptitude**.

The phrase also has a causative meaning and could be interpreted as an abridged adverbial of reason, since the sentence in question could be deemed to derive from:

- **AS (= BEING) descents to mental ineptitude**, those mechanical and untruthful habits of thought  are so pleasant and so easy.